# spring-boot-starter-freemarker does not find templates

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

Using `spring-boot-starter-freemarker` without further config I would expect to be able to load templates from the default template path(`src/resources/templates`) (note it's `src/...` not `build/...`).

Having this file here:

```
src/resources/templates/emails/welcome.ftl
```

Trying to load it as a template:

```
// some service class
  @Autowired
  private Configuration freemarkerConfig;

  public void doStuff() {
    Template t = freemarkerConfig.getTemplate("emails/welcome.ftl");
    // ...
  }
```

Fails with this error message:

```
freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "emails/welcome.text.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: MultiTemplateLoader(loader1 = FileTemplateLoader(baseDir="/some/path/backend/build/resources/main/templates", canonicalBasePath="/some/path/backend/build/resources/main/templates/"), loader2 = ClassTemplateLoader(resourceLoaderClass=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer, basePackagePath="" /* relatively to resourceLoaderClass pkg */)).
```

So the configuration seems kind of ok-ish, but instead of the `src` folder it is using the `build` folder. When running via`./gradlew bootRun` we see the error. Doing a `./gradlew build`and then `./gradlew bootRun` the templates are found - because they are now in the `build` folder. But for development it would be much appreciated to not require a full re-build.

So, I know we now could configure freemarker manually to load from the `src` folder, but that feels hacky.

Am I doing something wrong or is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure `bootRun` so that sources are loaded from their source location. Assuming that the templates are part of the main source set, i.e. they're in `src/main/resources`, the configuration would be the following:

```
bootRun {
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
}
```

This is [described](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#running-your-application-reloading-resources) in the reference documentation for Spring Boot's Gradle plugin.